# Remove two digit/symbol to find equality

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Find the equality by removing any two digits or symbols (of course, except equal sign)

> $4\div3+63=9-23\times7\div3$

For example, if the equation below was given,

> Example: $91-81=45+12\div3-85$

the answer would be by removing $1$ and $\div$:

> $91-8=45+123-85$

Comment: If I remove the 3 after the division sign, what happens to the operation? Does it become void?

Comment: @Sid yes, it becomes the equality invalid :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

> Remove a $6$ and a $3$ to get 
>
>  $4 \div 3 + 3 = 9 - 2 \times 7 \div 3$
>
>  which both results in $13 / 3$.